# How can i get arround, that a child produces something, i don't need in his parent neither?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

## Code is the best language

**Source [source.xml]**

```
<asset>
    <name>foobar</name>
    <paragraph>
        I <italic>describe</italic> a function <bold>foobar</bold>.
        <headline>I can't be in a paragraph!</headline>
        My editor did stuff like this: <bold>Cases: <list><li>item 1</li><li>item 2</li></list></bold>
    </paragraph>
</asset>
```

**Source DTD [source.dtd]**

```
<!ELEMENT asset (name,paragraph+)>
<!ELEMENT name (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT paragraph (#PCDATA|bold|headline|italic)*>
<!ELEMENT bold (#PCDATA|list)*>
<!ELEMENT italic (#PCDATA|list)>
<!ELEMENT headline (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT list (li)+>
<!ELEMENT li (#PCDATA)>
```

---

**expected output [output.xml]**

```
<asset>
    <name>foobar</name>
    <p>
        I <i>describe</i> a function <b>foobar</b>.
        </p><title>I can't be in a paragraph!</title><p>
            My editor did stuff like this: <b>Cases: </b>
    </p>
    <enum><item>item 1</item><item>item 2</item></enum>
</asset>
```

**Output DTD [output.dtd]**

```
<!ELEMENT asset (name,(title|p|enum)*)>
<!ELEMENT name (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT p (#PCDATA|b|i)*>
<!ELEMENT b (#PCDATA)*>
<!ELEMENT i (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT title (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT enum (item)+>
<!ELEMENT item (#PCDATA)>
```

---

**Description in words**

Simplified `source.xml` respectively `output.xml` are defined by their responsible dtd files. The changes are minor but important for my problem.

Element `headline`[source] is mapped to `title`[output] and must be a child of `asset`[output]. (previous/source: it was child of `paragraph`).

Element `list`[source] is mapped to `enum`[output] and must be a child of `asset`[output]. (previous/source: it was child of `bold`).

**XSLT problems begin**

I struggle to build a stylesheet with mainly rule-based templates, cause this example contains only about 4% of elements to work with. What do i expect to do:

- Whenever a "breakelement" occurs in my current node, the content till the "breakelement" gets copied, then the "breakelement" gets processed (apply-templates, cause there could be a matching rule for the "breakelement") after that (if there is content) the content of current node continues. You see that in the example of `p/headline` -> `asset/title`.
- Whenever i apply the same logic from above to element `bold`, it will produce following wrong content. `enum` will be outside of `b`, but now it is wrong, cause it must be outside of `p` as well:

Content:

```
<asset>
    <name>foobar</name>
    <p>
        I <i>describe</i> a function <b>foobar</b>.
        </p><title>I can't be in a paragraph!</title><p>
            My editor did stuff like this: <b>Cases: </b><enum><item>item 1</item><item>item 2</item></enum>
    </p>
</asset>
```

Second case will occur many times in my process from one schema to another schema, i can not handle so far.

> **How can i get arround, that a child produces something, i don't need in his parent neither?**

TBH i can't show any stylesheet, cause this is fully theoretical stuff. Please let me you understand my thread and described problem via comments as you usally do. Highly appreciate your effort, at least for taking time for reading.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to tackle that with `for-each-group group-ending-with="headline | list"`, here is my attempt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="asset">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each-group
                select="descendant::node()[not(ancestor::headline | ancestor::list)]"
                group-ending-with="headline | list">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()/ancestor::*[last() - 1]" mode="strip">
                    <xsl:with-param name="copy" tunnel="yes"
                        select="current-group()[position() ne last()]"/>
                </xsl:apply-templates>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()[last()]"/>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node()" mode="strip">
        <xsl:param name="copy" tunnel="yes"/>
        <xsl:if test=". intersect $copy or . intersect $copy/ancestor::*">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates
                    select="@* | node()[. intersect $copy/ancestor-or-self::node()]" mode="strip">
                    <xsl:with-param name="copy" tunnel="yes" select="$copy"/>
                </xsl:apply-templates>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="headline | list" mode="strip"/>

    <xsl:template match="headline">
        <title>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </title>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="list">
        <enum>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </enum>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="list/li">
        <item>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </item>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It transforms

```
<asset>
    <name>foobar</name>
    <paragraph>
        I <italic>describe</italic> a function <bold>foobar</bold>.
        <headline>I can't be in a paragraph!</headline>
        My editor did stuff like this: <bold>Cases: <list><li>item 1</li><li>item 2</li></list></bold>
    </paragraph>
</asset>
```

into

```
<asset>
   <name>foobar</name>
   <paragraph>
        I <italic>describe</italic> a function <bold>foobar</bold>.
        </paragraph>
   <title>I can't be in a paragraph!</title>
   <paragraph>
        My editor did stuff like this: <bold>Cases: </bold>
   </paragraph>
   <enum>
      <item>item 1</item>
      <item>item 2</item>
   </enum>
</asset>
```

Comment: i will give it a try in a few days. have you done something similiar to my problem in your past? thanks a lot for input.